# Quick punctuation request on a sentence containing a list with a colon per listed item

Tags: formatting, punctuation

This is being used within a blog article, however, I want to primp it up for use in a more public and professional platform. My intrigue pertains to grammar and punctuation of the listed items in the second line of the sentence below.

> For instance, there might be a time where inventory might result in
>
> Head: 3, Heart: 8, and Body: 10.

This sentence follows an image that provides a scale of physiological capability per body part of the head, heart, and body. This sentence is also fitted within a paragraph. The numbers reference the image's scale of a one to ten spectrum, so the number's mention here does not need mention of reference to the scale within this sentence.

My question: can this sentence be structured with colons as is, or would other punctuation be most fitting here? Comments on styling this are welcome.

Comment: I don't have a reference so I won't make this an answer; I think it looks fine as it is. The only other suitable punctuation IMO would be Head=3, Heart=8, Body=10. But for reading, I would prefer the colon to the equals sign.

Comment: That works as affirmation enough for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a list with additional punctuation in the items, I would use semicolons in place of the commas to separate the list items, like this:

> Head: 3; Heart: 8; and Body: 10.

Or one could restructure it into pute prose, such as this:

> The value for Head was 3, for Heart it was 8, and for Body it was 10.

This avoids the problem but is more wordy, and would not be suitable if there were very many more items.

Oh, if using = in place of a colon, I would also use semicolons to separate the list items, as:

> Head=3; Heart=8; Body=10.